# NDSolve with matrix variables and SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, variable

I'm experimenting with solution of differential equations with matrix variables, where the right hand side is defined as a numerically evaluated function of a matrix. Here is a simple example:

```
p0={{0,1,0},{0,1,0}}; v0={{1,0,0},{0,0,1}};
rhs[v_?(MatrixQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := -v;
sol=NDSolveValue[{v'[t]==rhs[p[t]],p'[t]==v[t],
 p[0]==p0,v[0]==v0}, {p,v}, {t, 0, 10}]
pos=sol[[1]]; vel=sol[[2]];
ParametricPlot3D[pos[t], {t, 0, 10},
 BoxRatios -> 1]
```

The example works. However, I would like to use SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta as integration method:

```
 sol=NDSolveValue[{v'[t]==rhs[p[t]],p'[t]==v[t],
 p[0]==p0,v[0]==v0}, {p,v}, {t, 0, 10},
 Method -> {"SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta",
 "DifferenceOrder" -> 2,
 "PositionVariables" :> p}]
```

This does not work:

```
NDSolveValue::sprkqv: The value of
 PositionsVariables -> p of the method
 SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta 
 is not a valid list of position
 variables.
NDSolveValue::initf: The initialization 
 of the method
 NDSolve`SymplecticPartitionedRungeKutta 
 failed.
```

Please help!

Comment: Lookt at the error message! :) You should give it a **list** of position variables, namely: `"PositionVariables" :> {p}`.